# add search capabilities and support for pages to a web application

Tags: java, full-text-search, ejb, jstl, html

I was wondering if there are any open source plugins or tutorials for adding search capabilities to a web application (to search my content only) and for adding support for pages with search or without it.

Also if possible can it be done using the basic template for web project in netbeans 7.0.1 with ejbs, java, jstl, servlet.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look on those(based on lucene):

1. http://compass-project.org/ - in case of very complex domain model
2. http://www.elasticsearch.org/ - in case of scalability requirements